# how to stop mongoose/javascript adding null values to arrays?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema which has a field of `comments: [String]`.

When I try to update the schema, I am checking if the value is null or empty by adding the following code into my controller,

`if (req.body.comments !== null || req.body.comments !== '') {
  container.comments.push(req.body.comments)
}`

`container.save() ...`

However when I run this code (using postman for testing) and do not provide a value for the comment field, it updates in the database as null in the array.

`comments: [String]` is in the main schema definition and not part of a suc-document or anything like that.

Would anybody know a way round this issue or why this happens?

Comment: If you do not provide a value comments is `undefined`, not `null`. You should check for that case as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that comments is not `undefined`, you can handle all cases this way:

```
if (req.body.comments && req.body.comments !== '') {
  container.comments.push(req.body.comments)
}
```

That way empty strings, null and undefined values are not added, assuming `req.body.comments` always comes in as a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution helped, it turns out that I had to use the `&&`  operator which you have used instead of the `||` operator which I was using

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `container.comments` as an empty array before you reach your condition statement

```
container.comments = container.comments || []
if (req.body.comments && req.body.comments !== '') {
  container.comments.push(req.body.comments)
}
```

this way the data saved on your database will always be an array, regardless of your sending comments on your request or not.

also its worth mentioning that saving an empty array on monggose will result to `undefined` unless you override it.

edited the example to take consideration if the array is not empty

Comment: your solution works but always creates an empty array, checking whether the array already exists before setting it to a new empty array is also workable in my case. thanks alot